# Serialize C++ classes between processes and across the network

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I'd like to understand how to transmit the contents of a C++ class between processes or across a network.

I'm reading the Google Protobuf tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

and it seems you must create an abstracted, non-C++ interface to represent your class:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package tutorial;

message Person {
  optional string name = 1;
  optional int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }
}
```

However, I'd prefer to specify my class via C++ code (rather than the abstraction) and just add something like `serialize()` and `deserialize()` methods.

Is this possible with Google Protobuf? Or is this how Protobuf works and I'd need to use a different serialization technique?

UPDATE

The reason for this is I don't want to have to maintain two interfaces. I'd prefer to have one C++ class, update it and not have to worry about a second `.proto` interface/definition. Code maintainability.

Comment: i used it once in combination with my handwritten C++ class, though I was fine with copying stuff from my class to the one generated from the .proto definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how Protobuf works. You have to use something else if you want to serialize your manually-written C++ classes. However, I'm not sure you *really* want that, because you then will have to either restrict yourself to very simple fields with no invariants (just like in Protobuf) or write custom (de)serialization logic yourself.

Comment: But surely at the end of the day, even a composite class is still eventually resolved down to primitives types? Maybe with pointers and strings and i'm sure that's been handled by a library?

Comment: @user997112 cpp isn't necessarily the ideal environment for code-first reflection code; tools to do what you want do exist in Java and .NET, but in cpp? Not so sure

Comment: @user997112 It sure will. You can try looking into the Boost::Serialization library, but there is no reflection in C++, so you will have to either resort to some kind of preprocessing/code generation, or write some code listing your fields manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple protocol buffer to hold binary information, but it sort of breaks the point of using Protocol buffers.

You can sort of cheat the system by using SerializeToString() and ParseFromString() to simply serialize binary information into a string.

There is also SerializeToOstream() and ParseFromIstream().

The real value of protocol buffers is being able to use messages across programs, systems and languages while using a single definition. If you aren't making messages using the protocol they've defined; this is more work than simply using native C++ capabilities.